# "One-sided" moments of the Standard normal distribution

Tags: probability

is there a general formula for the following integral involving the Gaussian distribution ($X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$):
    \begin{equation}
  I_n(z) = \mathbb{E}[X^n\mathbb{1}_{X>z}] = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^{+\infty}x^ne^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}dx
 \end{equation}
    for $z\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

I had a look at *Gradshteyn and Ryzhik*, *Table of integrals, series, and products* but I could only find the cases $3.321 2-7$ where $n=0,1,2,3,4$ and $u>0$.

Many thanks in advance

Comment: You can reduce that integral to an incomplete Beta.

Comment: Many thanks. Could you be more specific on how?

Comment: The change of variable is obvious.

Comment: Thanks then for the obviousness. Because n is an integer i could also apply integration by part and iterate without involving the beta. Unfortunately If possible I would really appreciate another solution

Comment: Care to look at what the Beta integral is !

Comment: Many thanks once more for the suggestion. Looking at the answer below I am afraid you were referring to the incomplete Gamma and not Beta.

Comment: Oooooops, my bad ! I was victim of my onw error function. Yep, Gamma. I have added the transformation.

Answer (score 1):

For even $n=2m$ with $m>0$ let the polynomial 
$$
E_m(z) \equiv \sum_{k=0}^{m-1}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k+1)!!}
$$
Then the integral is
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^\infty x^{2m}e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\,dx = 
(2m-1)!! \left( \frac12\mbox{ erfc}(\frac{z}{\sqrt{2}})+E_m(z) \frac{z}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}  \right)
$$

For odd $n=2m+1$ with $m\geq 0$ let
$$
K_m(z) \equiv (2m)!!\sum_{k=0}^{m}\frac{z^{2k}}{(2k)!!}
$$
with the convention that $0!! = 1$. Then the integral is
$$
\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_z^\infty x^{2m+1}e^{-\frac{x^2}2}\,dx = 
(2m)!! \left(  K_m(z) \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{z^2}{2}}  \right)
$$
The similarities, other than the lack of an erfc term, are great enough to combine the two expressions for odd and even cases, but that is not much of an improvement.

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_z^{\infty}x^ne^{-x^2/2}dx=2^{(n-1)/2}\int_{z^2/2}^{\infty}t^{(n-1)/2}e^{-t}dt=2^{(n-1)/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n+1}2,\frac{z^2}2\right)$$

where $\Gamma$ denotes the upper incomplete Gamma integral.

---

You can also establish a recurrence relation, by parts,

$$I_n(z)=\int_z^{\infty}x^ne^{-x^2/2}dx=\int_z^{\infty}x^{n-1}\,xe^{-x^2/2}dx\\
=-\left.x^{n-1}e^{-x^2/2}\right|_z^\infty+(n-1)\int_z^{\infty}x^{n-2}e^{-x^2/2}dx\\
=z^{n-1}e^{-z^2/2}+(n-1)I_{n-2}.$$

$I_0$ is solved by the error function and $I_1$ is elementary.

Comment: Answers $1$ and $2$ can be combined together knowing that the incomplete gamma  $\Gamma(n, z) = (n-1)!e^{-z}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{z^k}{k!}$ and $(2n)!! = 2^n n!$

Comment: @Piergiacomo: the incomplete Gamma does not have a closed-form expression !

Comment: Probably I was not explicit enough in my post or I am missing something, but I have the impression that $\Gamma(n, z)$ is known for $n$ integer.  See link http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html

Comment: @Piergiacomo: right for integer powers, but here we also have half-integers.